# Add extra context variables into django oscar emails

Tags: django, django-oscar

Trying to add extra context variables for all django oscar email templates. The only way I've got it to work is overriding specific views like ProfileUpdateView. This method seems very messy, I'd have to override a lot of files. Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up making a custom management command to do it manually since the need to change the emails templates would be really rare.

Answer (score 1):

From checking the source code, the `ProfileUpdateView` uses Django's Class Based View `FormView`, which in turn implements the `get_context_data` method allowing the injection of extra data in the view.
You can simply create a view inehiriting ProfileUpdateView and override the `get_context_data`:

```
class MyProfileUpdateView(ProfileUpdateView):
    ...
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MyProfileUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['somevar'] = SomeQueryMaybe.objects.all()
        return context
```

Comment: This would only add context to the view itself. My aim is to add context to the emails. Like how its been done around this [line](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/blob/174d4dcd675fedc319f55f4d2b94e83772c628e6/src/oscar/apps/customer/views.py#L332)